# Nested table rows in Vue

Tags: templates, vue.js

There has been several versions of this question, but I've found a specific scenario I can't get my head around. I have this template on a parent element:

```
<tbody>
    <tr is="tree-item" v-for="item in children" :item="item"></tr>
</tbody>
```

So far so good. The child element is:

```
<tr v-on:click="toggle" class="{{ classes }}">
    <td class="name">
        {{ item.tree_item_heading }}
    </td>
</tr>

<tr v-show="isLoaded" is="tree-item" v-for="item in grandChildren" :item="item"></tr>
```

It's a recursive form line, so if the first `tree-item` has children, they will render as `tree-item` too. Although it shows up fine, it is rendered as a Fragment Instance, hence the `v-show` property gets ignored.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could try using multiple tbody tags for your parent loop:

```
<tbody v-for='item in children'>
    <tr is="tree-item" :item="item"></tr>
    <tr v-show="isLoaded" is="tree-item" v-for="gItem in item.children" :item="gItem"></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this option, but then I get `tbody` inside `tbody`, which is still an illegal table layout and breaks it.

Comment: If you put a jsfiddle up to play with, I can try to take another look for you? I'm guessing that the "recursive" part of your question is what's causing it though - yes, the multiple tbody tag solution would die then...